# Adding watermark to web page - architecture

Tags: css, https, html, watermark, proxy-server

I am curious about adding watermarks to web pages, e.g. logo of internet provider. I'm not asking for code sample for HTML or CSS. I was thinking about proxy server which will add watermark to any web page that user tries to visit. How should proxy server behave when user asks for HTTPS website? Are there any other approaches apart from proxy server that I could try?

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Well, my question wasn't "Is it ok if I add watermark to webpage?", anyway thanks for your reply. Why in your opinion I shouldn't do that?

Comment: It's a great way to make your users despise you.  It's also impossible to automatically safely change the layout of an arbitrary page.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't thinking about commercial solution, but topic for my university project (cause it hasn't been made yet).

Answer (score 0):

Summary: You really don't want to do this.

There's only one way to do that luckily, and it's ugly, unreliable and insecure. You have to configure your proxy to act as a HTTPS terminator which intercepts the connections made from the client and create a new connection to the destination site. Now you can modify the data before sending it to the client.

However, the client expects an encrypted connection signed with the correct certificate. You don't have this certificate, so all browsers will just terminate the connection or, if you re-sign with your own certificate, complain about an invalid certificate. This will result in huge error messages on every client, so that'll be a problem.

You can avoid this by installing a new self-signed root certificate on all your client machines valid for all sites and sign the data with this certificate. Now your clients will accept the connection and will happily display the modified sites.

However, now you have broken the chain of trust implied by TLS and you're now solely responsible for the security between the client and the destination. When I connect to my bank the presence of TLS ensures me that I a) am connected to the real website of my bank and b) that no one can intercept my, for example, login details. You've broken both A and B, because I no longer can trust that I'm connected to the real website I intended to visit and you or any malicious third party can intercept and read the traffic between me and my bank just by abusing/hacking your proxy server.

Also, with techniques like [HTTP Public Key Pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) both sites and browsers are arming themselves against firewall vendors, AV companies and ISP's with bad ideas like this. Because that's just what this is, a very bad idea.

Please, please, don't do this.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I thought that it will be difficult with HTTPS but now I clearly see that it shouldn't be done. So with HTTP there shouldn't be any (big) problems, right?

Comment: Most likely not, but it depends on the exact implementation and environment. And honestly I fail to see why you would even want to do this.

Comment: I was interested if it is possible to do that and if it is I want to try to implement it. E.g. anyone using my home WiFi network will see "Internet connection provided by Anon" while visiting any website.

Comment: So if I wanted to that, what architecture would you suggest?